# JavaFX OnDragDrop handler doesn't work

Tags: listview, drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I'm trying to implement Drag&Drop an item from ListView using JavaFX. All handlers  work such as onDragDetected , onDragEnter except onDragDrop.

there are toolbax.fxml which has listView and it is included in main.fxml.

Here are sections of my codes:

**toolbax.fxml:**

```
 <ListView fx:id="source" layoutX="-9.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <items>
              <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList" >
                  <HBox onDragDetected="#handleDragDetected" onDragDone="#handleDragDone" >
                     <children>
                         <ImageView>
                             <image>
                                   <Image requestedHeight="40" requestedWidth="40" url="@/resources/computer.png" />
                             </image>
                         </ImageView>
                         <Text text="Host" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                         <ImageView>
                             <image>
                                 <Image requestedHeight="40" requestedWidth="40" url="@/resources/server.png" />
                             </image>
                         </ImageView>
                         <Text text="Server" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
              </FXCollections>

        </items>
  </ListView>
```

**toolbaxController:**

```
public class ToolboxController {
@FXML
private ListView<FXCollections> source;
public static DataFormat dataFormat =  new DataFormat("myCell");

@FXML
private void handleDragDetected(MouseEvent event)
{



    System.out.println("onDragDetected");

    Dragboard db=source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

    int id=source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.put(dataFormat,id);
    db.setContent(content);

    event.consume();


}


@FXML
void handleDragDone(DragEvent event)
{

    System.out.println("onDragDone");

    if(event.getTransferMode()==TransferMode.MOVE)
    {
      //  source
    }
    event.consume();
}
```

}

**main.fxml:**

```
 <center>
  <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <ImageView  onDragDropped="#handleDragDrop" onDragEntered="#handleDragEntered" onDragExited="#handleDragExited" onDragOver="#handleDragOver" fx:id="target" fitHeight="253.0" fitWidth="320.0" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
     </children></AnchorPane>
```

**mainController:**

```
public class MainController {
@FXML
private ImageView target;




@FXML
void handleDragOver(DragEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("onDragOver");

    if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
            event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
        target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: aqua");
        /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
    }

    event.consume();
}

@FXML void handleDragEntered(DragEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("onDragEntered");
    if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
            event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
        target.setStyle("-fx-background-color:brown");
    }

    event.consume();

}

@FXML
void handleDragExited(DragEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("onDragExited");

    target.setStyle("-fx-background-color:darkblue");


    event.consume();
}
@FXML
public void handleDragDrop(DragEvent event)
{

    System.out.println("onDragDrop");
    Object obj;
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    if (db.hasContent(ToolboxController.dataFormat) ){
        obj=db.getContent(ToolboxController.dataFormat);
        success = true;
        System.out.println("onDragDrop");
    }
    /* let the source know whether the string was successfully
     * transferred and used */
    event.setDropCompleted(success);

    event.consume();
}
```

}

and its my output when I drag an item from ListView on ImageView:

> onDragDetected
>
> onDragEntered
>
> onDragOver
>
> onDragOver
>
> onDragOver
>
> onDragOver
>
> onDragExited

which means handleDragDrop doesn't execute.I wonder maybe the problem is target, I mean maybe target mustn't be AnchorPane or ImageView .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the Ansewer, It was so Stupid :) , when you use onDragExited handler your OnDragDrop handler doesn't execute. So you should choose which one you want to use.